# Replace space with underscore in table

Tags: mysql, special-characters, case-sensitive

How can I write a SQL query to  replace all occurrences of space in a table with underscore and set all characters to lowercase?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To update a single column in a single table, you can use a combination of [`LOWER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) and [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name=LOWER(REPLACE(column_name, ' ', '_'))
```

To "duplicate" the existing column, and perform the updates on the duplicate (per your question in a comment), you can use MySQL's `ALTER` command before the `UPDATE` query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD duplicate_column_name VARCHAR(255) AFTER column_name;
UPDATE table_name SET duplicate_column_name = LOWER(REPLACE(column_name, ' ', '_'));
```

Just be sure to update the data-type in the `ALTER` command to reflect your actual data-type.

Comment: would this work for the entire table in one query? Wouldn't be need to iterate through each row to get this working?

Comment: first I need to duplicate the column. How do I do that?

Comment: @mlishn This will work for an entire column in the given table; If he needs multiple columns in the same table he could append them to the update clause. If he needs multiple tables, he could use either multiple `UPDATE` clauses - or write a stored procedure that iterates through `information_schema`.

Comment: @newfurniturey great answer then :)

Comment: @mark I've updated my answer to show how to duplicate the column first.

Answer (score 0):

When using the UPDATE statement in SQL, always remember to include a WHERE clause -- so says MYSQL Workbench! :D

My Answer though:

```
REPLACE(string1, find_in_string, replacementValue);
```